# How to sum datagridview rows.values that are greater than 0 in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i had this code that calculate the sum of values in a datagridview columnrows;

```
   Private Sub GetSUMofUnits()
       Dim total As Integer

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvSubjects.Rows
        total += row.Cells(3).Value
    Next
    txtTotalUnits.Text = total
   End Sub
```

But, i want to sum only the values that are greater than 0;

For example, this is my datagridview columns("Units");

```
    Units
      3
      3
      2
     -3
Total 8
```

It should calculate only the value in a datagridview cell that are greater than 0.

How do i do this? Thanks a lot...

Comment: If you've done any basic reading on VB.NET then you know how to use an `If` statement.

Comment: How do i include in my existing code.. i'm just new with vb.net so technically i really need a little help on this..thanks man..

Comment: Seriously, you're not going to make many friends around here asking how to implement an `If` statement. That's about as basic as it gets. We're not here to teach the basics. Think about. Programming doesn't exist in a vacuum. What would you do if this was a manual process? You'd check to see whether a required condition for a task was satisfied and then only perform the task if it was. It's not different in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply like this :

```
Private Sub GetSUMofUnits()
    Dim total As Integer

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvSubjects.Rows
        If row.Cells(3).Value > 0
            total += row.Cells(3).Value
        End If
    Next
    txtTotalUnits.Text = total
End Sub
```

**Hope it helped :)**

Comment: Yeah, you'er learning so nothing wrong with that, you'er welcome :)

Comment: Hello bro, i just posted another question, TITLE "How to make the values in a datagridview columns to accounting format", Maybe you can give me solution for this? thanks a lot man..

Comment: @Diaval , Yeah i will look at it.